# rebuild by updating files under node_modules with #module-source-map makes heap out of memory

Tags: webpack, node-modules, source-maps

- node@6.2.2
- webpack@1.12.15
- devtool: #module-source-map

When i update files under my project, the rebuild is fast

But when i update files under node_modules, it takes a lot of time(even display 1/1 build modules) and makes heap out of memory

Here's the logs

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  277985 ms: Mark-sweep 1218.5 (1435.0) -> 1213.7 (1435.0) MB, 1232.2 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  279006 ms: Mark-sweep 1213.7 (1435.0) -> 1213.7 (1435.0) MB, 1020.8 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  280087 ms: Mark-sweep 1213.7 (1435.0) -> 1213.6 (1435.0) MB, 1080.4 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  281358 ms: Mark-sweep 1213.6 (1435.0) -> 1213.6 (1435.0) MB, 1271.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xc3785fc9e59 <JS Object>
    1: node [/Users/Jared/project/module-name/node_modules/.npminstall/webpack-core/0.6.8/webpack-core/lib/OriginalSource.js:~53] [pc=0xbae9b454acb] (this=0x38b12b4e66c9 <an OriginalSource with map 0x2cfe7ecd6181>,options=0x27c599c611c9 <an Object with map 0x2cfe7ec6e061>)
    2: node [/Users/Jared/project/module-name/node_modules/.npminstall/webpack-core/0.6.8/webpack-core/lib/ReplaceSource.js:~62] [pc=0xbae9b452f...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Answer (score 0):

Node sets maximum size limit of heap to 1.7 GB. You can increase heap for node process.

```
node --max_old_space_size=2048 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config config/webpack.prod.js
```

Here 2048 means 2 GB, You can change it as per requirement.